# Finding properties description in Freebase with MQL

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm getting crazy trying to fetch properties description, i mean the ones that appear in the schema...

1) the text service doesn't find properties description:
  https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/people/person/profession

2) properties doesn't include /common/topic so they haven't /common/topic/description?! am I right?

3) the /freebase/property_hint (or something...) doesn't work for descriptions...

thanks
luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text for property descriptions is stored in /freebase/documented_object/tip. You can query it [like this](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/people/person/profession%22,%22/freebase/documented_object/tip%22%3anull%7D):

```
{
  "id": "/people/person/profession",
  "/freebase/documented_object/tip": null
}​
```

To figure these sorts of problems out, I often find it useful to scroll through the raw Freebase triples for a topic like this:

http://dev.freebase.com/people/person/profession?links

There you can see the direct relationship between the schema and the data.

Comment: Thanks Shawn! is exactly what i was looking for! wow the dev page is really useful! i'll check it out next time!

Comment: dev.freebase.com is the new (development) version of Freebase.com that we're working on. There's a similar feature on the current Freebase.com called "inspect" but its better to get used to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Text API with the property's ID e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/type/property

As an aside, an object doesn't need to have a specific type have a property from that type, if you were, for example, to look at the /type/property object, you'd see that it does in fact have a /common/topic/article property that you could follow to lead eventually to the text blob, but using the Text API is way easier.

Comment: Thanks Tom, but I can't understand how to use it...for example in the [/people/person schema](http://www.freebase.com/schema/people/person) you can see that /people/person/profession has a description, but calling the Text API with that property doesn't work: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/people/person/profession